# How many of the congressional seats that the Democrats lost since the 2008 election are due to gerrymandering?

Tags: united-states, congress

Gerrymandering is often given as one explanation of why the Democrats lost congressional seats to the Republicans. Is there any good analysis about how many seats were lost because of gerrymandering that happened after 2008? To what extent have changes in district lines resulted in the Republicans gaining more seats?

Comment: One of the issues is that it is very difficult to say what exactly is and isn't gerrymandered in any empirical way. There *are* legitimate reasons to draw "whacky" district lines, which is why they're drawn in the first place, instead of just using a simple grid system.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker : I edited my question to make it more clear that I'm talking about the effected of changes in district lines since 2008.

Comment: Is it possible to attribute the loss of a particular seat to gerrymandering?

Comment: What is the definition of gerrymandering as used in this question?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker "objective" is more appropriate than "empirical". "Empirical" refers to what actually happened, which is not at issue. What is at issue is the definitions.

Comment: Yeah, that's indeed what I intended to say but phrased poorly @Acccumulation. Can't edit comments :-(

Comment: According to 538 (including last week's Gerrymandering podcast as well as earlier posts), negligible effect. Most of the effect is from self-sorting of population, and gerrymandering has at best marginal effect, further reduced by the fact that gerrymanderings in different locales cancel each other out (both partisan ones and other ones)

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - not incontrovertibly, but there are methods that are better than a coin toss as far as attribution reliability :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [Cook Partisan Voting Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook_Partisan_Voting_Index), the effect seems to be negligible.

Looking at the PVI for the 2010 election, which was the last one to be used under the old district boundaries, the Republican candidate outperformed their national result in 235 districts, whereas the Democratic candidate outperformed in 192 districts.  8 districts were even with the national result. [Source](http://electoral-vote.com/evp2010/House/house.html)

These numbers are not significantly different ahead of next year's midterms.  The Republican candidate outperformed their national result in 238 districts, compared to 189 for Democrats.  Again, 8 were even with the national result. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook_Partisan_Voting_Index#By_congressional_district)

The swing here is only three seats, which in my opinion is not statistically significant.

Comment: 'Statistical significance' is not a matter of opinion, it is a well-defined concept in statistics.

Answer (score 0):

According to analysis by the [Associated Press](https://www.apnews.com/fa6478e10cda4e9cbd75380e705bd380), the GOP benefited a bit from gerrymandering:

> The AP analysis also found that Republicans won as many as 22 additional U.S. House seats [in 2016] over what would have been expected based on the average vote share in congressional districts across the country.

The [NYT](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/08/02/upshot/its-time-to-end-the-old-debate-over-gerrymandering.html) shows that the effect was a bit less in 2012:

> Most of the political-science-based estimates suggested that gerrymandering cost the Democrats a net of 7 to 12 seats in 2012 (with a few estimates coming in higher and lower).

Analysis by the [Brennan Center](https://www.brennancenter.org/press-release/new-report-extreme-partisan-maps-account-16-17-republican-seats-congress) concludes:

> [A] new report from the Brennan Center for Justice at NYU School of Law finds that extreme partisan bias in congressional maps account for at least 16-17 Republican seats in the current Congress